# onKeyPreIme in AutoCompleteTextView not called

Tags: android

I have subclassed AutoCompleteTextView to capture key presses from soft keyboard, but I am not able to capture key presses.

Here is my code for my custom AutoCompleteTextView.

```
public class CustomAutoCompleteTextView extends AutoCompleteTextView {

    public CustomAutoCompleteTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        //Do something here

        return super.onKeyPreIme(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

I have used in in my layout file

```
        <com.vipul.testapp.CustomAutoCompleteTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/field"
            android:editable="false"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
            android:textColor="@color/textColor"
            android:dropDownWidth="match_parent" />
```

Comment: Hi try after removing android:editable="false"

Comment: @selva tried, did not work.